# Is there a short Daf Yomi shiur online in English?

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, internet, english, daf-yomi

There is a short, 10-minute daf yomi shiur in Hebrew [here](http://www.sinai.org.il/) :  and I was wondering if there is anything comparable in English. I'm looking for a Daf Yomi shiur online that is significantly shorter than the normal 45-60 minutes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Daf Yomi Online by Eliyahu Fink. Around 20 minutes a Daf and yet clear and concise.This can be found on iTunes for free.

[Here's](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/daf-yomi-online/id549612151?mt=2&ign-mpt=uo%3D4) the: Or you can just search for it on itunes.
Or [here](http://daf.finkorswim.com/) : 
He also has a [YouTube](http://youtube.com/user/rabbifink) channel, which may be useful if you have connectivity issues with his website.

Each Daf is about 20 minutes, on average, but pretty understandable. Currently covers Berachot 2 - Yoma 17.

Comment: He no longer does the Shi'ur. It was good while it lasted.

Comment: I'm currently using this, but i'm having trouble with it because he often has to go back and correct his understanding of passages.

Comment: Can you update the dead links?

Answer (score 7):

Master Daf is an unusually clear 20 minute daf yomi shiur in english, with every word read and translated, available on all of Shas. Maggid Shiur is a R`m in Slabodka Yeshiva of Bnai Brak.....available for purchase at [RabbiKosman.com](http://rabbikosman.com/)

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Arthur and thanks for this first answer. Hope to see you around!

Answer (score 6):

The shiurim of [R' Moshe Meir Weiss](http://www.kolhashiurim.com/New/Ravs.aspx?Path=English%7CEGmr%7CDafHaYomi%7CR7004-1-4&English=True) are very concise. Many are 15-30 minutes, though some run quite a bit longer (depending on the complexity, I guess).

10 minutes sounds like a completely unreasonable (and incomprehensible) speed. It might be useful for review purposes, but that's about it.

Answer (score 3):

I know of nothing that short that covers the entire daf, and nothing that's audio.  In case written sources help:

The following site does short summaries/excerpts every day (a couple hundred words, quick reads): http://dafyomi.livejournal.com/.

The Daf Yomi Advancement Forum publishes point-by-point summaries; see http://www.dafyomi.co.il/chulin/points/points.htm for the current masechta.

Answer (score 3):

There are shiurim called Chazarah Mp3. I don't know who the maggid shiur is, but he is pretty clear and speaks out almost all of the Rashis. His average is between 15-20 minutes a daf. The catch is that the shiurim cost, but they are only $5 a masechta.

Answer (score 3):

Rabbi Shmuel Herzfeld does the 5-minute Daf Yomi podcast on [Podbean](https://rabbishmuelherzfeld.podbean.com/) and possibly other apps. it is usually under 7 minutes, He talks fast and covers the important points. He also tries to draw a relevant point out at the end,

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Jo and thanks for this first answer. If you know how to add a link, that is always welcome, I did it for you here in case that wasn't clear (you can see it if you edit your answer). Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 2):

There is a daily 8-minute shiur given by Rabbi Eli Stefansky. It is broadcast live on Youtube, and accessible on his [channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCaO4oFhKPfIvXQgzVoq8cVw?app=desktop).

Comment: But it looks like they usually run more than 40 minutes?  Am I missing where the 8 minute ones are (or are they live and not saved)?

Comment: @Mordechai From the provided link I see what you mean. He probably means [this](https://m.youtube.com/channel/UCaO4oFhKPfIvXQgzVoq8cVw) channel which seems to be fairly new.

Comment: @Oliver - Thank you. I'll edit the post to change the link...

Comment: @chortkov2 You’re welcome. While you’re at it you might consider rephrasing to “...review/overview shiur”; it’s not a Daf Yomi shiur in the typical sense having the daf read.

Answer (score 2):

There is Quick Daf by Rabbi Zecharia Resnik which can be found on All Daf app. He is very clear and quick. Each shiur is different but average is like  around 10-15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a review of a couple English shiurim listed [here](http://ravlachemshevet.blogspot.co.il/p/reviw-of-daf-yomi-audio-shiurim.html) including average length, audio quality, format, etc. Some are listed as "fast".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Daf Yomi given over in under 30 minutes. Clear, Fast & Easy. A Rashi here and there with a Tosfos as well.

https://chat.whatsapp.com/IltfkmD76kX8RQuv4i0bjN

Answer (score 0):

I came across the following:
Daf Hayomi Quick Vort - Zwi Y. Sacho

Have you got less than 5 minutes to learn Daf Hayomi?

Join 'Daf Hayomi Quick Vort'

It is a short summary of one or more ideas from every day's daf of Gemara learned on the Daf Hayomi programme.

Follow this link to join the group - https://chat.whatsapp.com/IBct4XdiebXKKUlmCD7XvQ

Archived shiurim are saved here -
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Dl_Ilf-yHd86b0ZTr5Gauy-VkhY8tn17

Answer (score 0):

The attached is a link to English Daf Yomi in 10 minutes:

https://chat.whatsapp.com/Cyt6jfAQf9Y3wiVWgbewgt

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first answer. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!