# Is there a Shiur/Book on Talmud Bavli that has Rashi Inside Translated in English?

Tags: product-recommendation, rashi, talmud-bavli, english

Is there a shiur online on Gemorah that has Rashi inside said over in English, explaining the simple meaning well? (length should be 30-60 minutes)

Alternatively, is there a book on Talmud Bavli that has Rashi translated, word for word?

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17338/online-english-rashi-talmud

Comment: FWIW, Steinsaltz incorporates Rashi quite heavily into his commentary.

Comment: that was in 2012 and there are no answers that answer my question. And even so I think I asked 2 questions beside that question 1 very different and 1 different

Comment: Somewhat related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8745/

Comment: @user613 see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/ (though *some* aspects of that are obsolete)

Comment: Many live / neighborhood shi'urim have people that explain Rashi in English. You can also arrange a chevruta either locally or via internet. If your talking about one already available like on YouTube or some other site, search and you should be able to locate something. Na'aleh (I may have the exact spelling wrong) or YU Torah should have some shiurim that do the job.

Comment: I dont think you are going about it the right way. Why do you really need rashi once you know the pshat in the gemoro from your english translation. Rashi is in hebrew not aramaic so you really should be learning hebrew.

Comment: I am talking about shiurim online.

Comment: @preferred I want to learn better hebrew so if I learn with DafYomi with the Rashi everyday then my hebrew will become much better over the days. And Rashi is good to help kids with there homework etc.

Comment: @user613 Dont think thats the way to learn hebrew.

Comment: @user613 - I can personally vouch for what preferred just said. You won't learn Hebrew by reading Rashi's English translation. That will help you understand that Rashi (and the pasuk), only. I learned Hebrew in Elementary school by extensive conversation, and learning vocabulary befor I learned Chumash. We then applied or Hebrew knowledge to the Chumash words. My kids, in contrast, never learned Hebrew and have minimal skills understanding the Rashi Hebrew w/o a lot of peeking in "Uncle Artie".

Comment: @DanF My goal is not to learn Hebrew my goal is to learn how to learn on my own Rashi I have a medium skill of hebrew in general but I can't complete a rashi. So I want a english translation word by word so that I know the meaning of every word and then without looking in the english look at the orignal Rashi text and translate it. And Rashi uses a lot of words from the gemorah and other words. So if I learn the Gemorah I know all the words from the gemorah and the other words some of them I need a translation of them so then upon every Rashi those words that I need translating will be fewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On dafyomi.org I just saw they have it. But I only heard it on Mesechta Rosh Hashana I do not know on the other mesechtos.

Answer (score 2):

There is a shiur in english at [RabbiKosman.com](http://rabbikosman.com/) called Master Rashi
Available currently on 7 mesechtos...very clear, every word read inside.

Answer (score 1):

To quote my answer to a duplicate question ([Gamara Rashi Shiur in English](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/114113/gamara-rashi-shiur-in-english)):
[Rabbi Moshe Pessin's][0] is just the shiur for you! To quote the person in charge (who contacted TorahDownloads.com which I volunteer for), " I have a unique shiur that I got a talmid chachum to give, nothing else exists like it. I want to get it out there as much as possible. (We are currently working with him to get them on TorahDownloads). JUST RASHI on the daf so that people can listen or learn the daf however they want and then listen to this 8-12 min shiur. " As of this writing (06/2021) he is up to Yoma, but the shiur he put out yesterday is titled "Yoma 58 - RASHI ONLY", so it seems to fit the bill. Unfortunately, that is a while from Megillah, though I am in touch with the person in charge of managing the shiurim, and am waiting to see if he has shiurim on Megillah.

P.S: forgive the formatting, I am on my phone.

0: https://www.yutorah.org/rabbi-moshe-pessin/